# object in foreground with ambient light and shadows

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I need to detect the cylinder that appears in an image. I need to get with precision its edges (left and right edges).

As the camera always captures the images, I though removing the background would keep only the object which is in the foreground. But the problem is image subtraction is not very precise. And also when the object is present I makes shadows in background and difference in the lighting which modifies the background image. Also the light may vary through the day.

background:
[image: background]

Foreground with object (cylinder):
[image: Foreground with object (cylinder)]

I need to do this in on image or maximum 5 (the MOG wouldn't work I think as it needs a video). I need a processing technique for a frame per frame.

This is the approach I used using a library I found on the internet for background subtraction on images ( PlantCV) :

```
def detection(foreground,background) :

foreground = cv2.cvtColor(foreground, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

bkg_sub_img = pcv.image_subtract(foreground,background)
bkg_sub_thres_img, masked_img = pcv.threshold.custom_range(rgb_img=bkg_sub_img, lower_thresh=[0],
                                                           upper_thresh=[150], channel='gray')
lp_img = pcv.laplace_filter(gray_img=masked_img, ksize=1, scale=1)
bkg_sub_img = pcv.image_subtract(foreground,lp_img)

cannyed = auto_canny(bkg_sub_img)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    cannyed,
    cv2.HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC,
    theta=np.pi / 180,
    threshold=20,
    lines=np.array([]),
    minLineLength=200,
    maxLineGap=50,
)

if lines is None:
    result = None
    err = "No pipe detected"
elif len(lines) < 2:
    result = None
    err = "Only one edge of the pipe is detected"
left_edge=[[5000,0,0,0]]
righ_edge=[[0,0,0,0]]

if lines is not None:

    for l in lines:

        x0 = l[0][0]
        y0 = l[0][1]
        x1 = l[0][2]
        y1 = l[0][3]
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y0 - y1, x0 - x1))

        if 85<np.abs(angle) < 95 :
         
            if x0 < left_edge[0][0] :
                left_edge=l

            if x0 > righ_edge[0][0] :
                righ_edge=l
```

The workflow is simple:

1. background subtraction using PlantCV
2. Canny edge detection
3. Hough lines detection
4. keep only the edges of the cylinder (most left and right lines)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Asking these questions without showing minimal effort is not appreciated.

Comment: Good point. I added the workflow I tried and a code I used.

Comment: if you are only interested in the vertical edges of the cylinder - you can do better than Canny - you can simply design a filter for long vertical edges.